# NgRx calling actions from effects at the beginning

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to dispatch an action before or at the beginning of an effect.

Small example:

```
saveSomething$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(SaveProjectAction),
      tap(() => ImSavingNowAction()), // trigger action here
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectSomething)),
      mergeMap(([action, project]) => {
        let save$ = this.api.call(something); // Do an api call or something that takes long here


        return save$.pipe(
          map(
            (project) => SavedSomethingAction({ something }),// Next Action to be called
            catchError(() => EMPTY)
          )
        );
      })
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to handle it in the `reducer` directly once the first action is dispatched, and there is no need to dispatch the `ImSavingNowAction` action from the `effect`.

In general, the best practice in effect is to handle one or many actions and map them to a singular action, without dispatching any other `action`(s) within it.

You can check [no-dispatch-in-effects](https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/no-dispatch-in-effects.md) and [no-multiple-actions-in-effects](https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/no-multiple-actions-in-effects.md) rules for more details.

Comment: This. Also if it's really needed consider splitting your effects into two, one that dispatched the first action, then another effect that listens to that action.